# Starting new Activities and adding them to a Fragment-based layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-actionbar

I'm pretty new to Fragments API and here's my question: let's say I have an `Activity` and an `ActionBar` with tabs. Suppose I want to start messaging application from my application and usually it will start as a new `Activity`. Is it possible to add the messaging `Activity` as a new tab to my `Activity`? How can I achieve this effect? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your onCreate method do the following

```
      Context context = getApplicationContext();
     ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
    actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    ActionBar.Tab PlayerTab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Fragment A");
    ActionBar.Tab StationsTab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Fragment B");

    Fragment PlayerFragment = new AFragment();
    Fragment StationsFragment = new BFragment();

    PlayerTab.setTabListener(new MsgTabsListener(PlayerFragment, context));
    StationsTab.setTabListener(new MsgTabsListener(StationsFragment, context));

    actionbar.addTab(PlayerTab);
    actionbar.addTab(StationsTab);
```

Then add the class `MsgTabListener` and do the following

```
class MsgTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
public Fragment fragment;
public Context context;

public MsgTabsListener(Fragment fragment, Context context) {
    this.fragment = fragment;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

//Start a new activity here with respect to your main context.
 context.StartActivity(new Intent(....));     

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    ft.remove(fragment);
}
```

If you are looking for good Fragements API tutorial then Lars Vogel has very nice explanations.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html#fragments_tutorial